# Disable auto launch of on-screen layout in Windows 8.1 App

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 Application written in C#/Xaml.

When I launch my application, the on screen keyboard opens automatically even when a physical keyboard is connected. This happens in some tablet devices like Lenovo IdeaPad. And it directly opens numerical on screen layout instead of the default alphabetical layout.

I have a normal xaml page with just one TextBox on my page. But still the on-screen keyboard pops up even though physical keyboard is attached. I have noticed that this doesn't happen on other Microsoft Tablet apps like Store and Internet Explorer.

I would be glad if someone can guide me as to how I can disable it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if such a thing exists , but you might want to try Focusing some other element after InitializeComponent method in constructor.

It's not what you're looking for but might be a good workaround.